# constraint getTargets method

Tags: php, symfony

When I create my own constraint, I have to set `getTargets()`

From api, I can read:

> Returns whether the constraint can be put onto classes, properties or
>   both
>
> This method should return one or more of the constants
>   Constraint::CLASSCONSTRAINT and Constraint::PROPERTYCONSTRAINT.

What is difference between these values?

Answer (score 0):

With `ClassConstraint` you can annotate a whole class, so the value you'll receive in `validate` method will be the whole classe

With `PropertyConstraint` you can annotate only a method, so the vale you'll receive in `validate` method will be the value of that property

Comment: Sorry but, I dont understand, I try `getTargets` two returns `return self::PROPERTY_CONSTRAINT;` and `return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;` 

And in my validator method `public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)`

`$value` and `$constraint` don't change, when I change return values in `getTargets`